# Inheritance vs Handle in OO Langugage

Tags: c++, oop

Whats the difference between an Interface and Handle

Handle - Implementation is in another class (Handle : Exposes all the functionality of a class, but the actual implementation is coded in another class. Handle contains pointer to the implementation class(pimpl idiom). Handle is like a wrapper class.)

Interface - Implementation is in the derived class

Is this is the only difference ?

Where do we use Interface, and where do we use Handle ?

Comment: Your title doesn't match what you typed...

Comment: Could you clarify [what sort of handle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303123/what-is-a-handle-in-c) you're talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Handle" doesn't have a widely agreed upon meaning with respect to C++. Different people use it to mean entirely different things (e.g., on Windows, "handle" does have a fairly well-defined meaning, so people programming Windows in C++ tend to use it the way Windows does).

As far as implementation in another class, that sounds more like a pimpl than what most people would usually call a handle. If that's the sort of thing you're talking about, it's quite a bit different from inheritance in both implementation and use. In fact, in many ways it's kind of the opposite: inheritance allows classes that are different from each other to be treated as if they were the same. With a pimpl, you have two classes that are identical (in some ways) but you still keep them entirely separate.

As to where/why you use them: with an interface (usually an ABC, in C++) you allow new derived classes to be manipulated via an existing interface, so existing code can use your new code without that existing code needing modification to do so.

pimpl is typically used primarily as a compiler firewall -- if you have some code that's changing frequently, but you don't want to re-compile everything that depends on it every time you change it, a pimpl can be helpful (though definitely not a panacea).

A handle is typically used to mean an opaque data type -- a "magic cookie" that gives you access to some capabilities, but which you can't/don't look at or manipulate directly at all. To some extent, you could consider any reference/pointer to almost any class as a handle (of sorts), but it's pretty unusual to hear/see the term used that way. More often it's something like a `FILE *` in C -- when you call `fopen`, it gives you the `FILE *`. Anytime you want to operate on the handle you opened, you pass that same `FILE *` back to the function you're going to use. You, however, aren't ever supposed to look "inside" to see what it points at, how that's used, or much of anything else (and at the Unix level using open/lseek/lread, etc., a file descriptor is pretty much the same way).

Perhaps you're thinking of something close to the handle/body idiom that was popular in relatively early C++. In this idiom, you did have implementation in another class. Specifically, the "handle" typically provided reference counting, and the body the implementation of whatever actions were needed on the single item to which you had those multiple (counted) references. The handle "handled" the reference count, and passed almost everything else through to the implementation class. This usage is no longer common for the simple reason that reference counting has largely fallen out of favor. Especially in a multi-threaded environment, reference counting can (and frequently does) have fairly substantial speed penalties, so its use is now relatively unusual (where at one time it was nearly expected of most classes that might manage substantial amounts of data).

Answer (score 3):

C++ does not include the concepts of either interface or handle, so specifically in this language it is technically correct to say that they are what you make of them.

That said, it sounds like you have the concepts somewhat confused (the fact that there is no authoritative definition certainly doesn't help).

Typically, a *handle* is some kind of value that uniquely describes an object, but the manner in which it does so is not known to whoever holds the handle. Instead, there is some third party that knows how to go from handles to actual objects and back and the holder has to go through that entity whenever they need access to the actual object. That is exactly the rationale for handles (from the point of view of the third party): you don't want others to mess with your objects unless you know about it, so you hide them behind opaque handles.

Trying to define an interface is more difficult because there are many good candidates, depending on context:

- we can say that the interface of a class is the set of its public methods and their signatures; it's what you have to work with if you are given an instance of that class
- we can also say that a class with only `public virtual` methods and no data members *is* an interface, in the sense that it models a contract between two entities ("you are only allowed to call this method, but when you do I promise to respond like this")

If you want a more specific answer, you will have to clarify the question first of all with yourself and then with the rest of us.